# How do I stop Media Player from playing multiple sounds on top of each other

Tags: android, audio, media-player

How do I stop MediaPlayer to play on top of each other? I want my Media Player in application to play only 1 sound.
Right now it's when I play 1 sound, and then play another sound they both play at same time. I want when I play 2nd sound, 1st to stop so they don't play on top of each other.
My code:

```
 mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.barets);
    ImageButton dugme1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dugme1);
    dugme1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.pause();
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp.start();
            }
            }

    });

    mp2=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dragunov);
    ImageButton dugme2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dugme2);
    dugme2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp2.isPlaying()){
                mp2.pause();
                mp2.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp2.start();
            }
            }

    });

    mp3=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.g3s);
    ImageButton dugme3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dugme3);
    dugme3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp3.isPlaying()){
                mp3.pause();
                mp3.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp3.start();
            }
            }

    });
    mp4=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.psg1);
    ImageButton dugme4= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dugme4);
    dugme4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp4.isPlaying()){
                mp4.pause();
                mp4.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp4.start();
            }
            }

    });

    mp5=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.scout);
    ImageButton dugme5= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dugme5);
    dugme5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp5.isPlaying()){
                mp5.pause();
                mp5.seekTo(0);
            }
            else{
                mp5.start();
            }
            }

    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only checking if your *current* mediaplayer is playing or not, that is, in mp, you are only checking mp, and so on.

You need to stop/pause **all** other MediaPlayers *before* you start playing one of them. Before starting any of them, *check if any of the other four are running*. If they are, then *stop/pause* them and *after* doing this for all **playing** media players, start the current media player.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you are starting new song, pause previous and only then play new song. Be careful when you need to stop song when activity is being closed, even then you need to shut down all audio playbacks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems obvious to me...Not even one of your six players knows of the other five. How could the other five stop when you click on any of the buttons? In the click event handling procedure check the list of players and see if there are any playing and pause them. Simple, no? :) But first you need a list of your players that each player must have access to.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that will stop any other players if they are playing and call it before starting playing in current player:

```
private void stopPlayers() {
    if (mp.isPlaying) mp.stop();
    if (mp2.isPlaying) mp2.stop();
    if (mp3.isPlaying) mp3.stop();
    if (mp4.isPlaying) mp4.stop();
    if (mp5.isPlaying) mp5.stop();
}
```

Call it in each listener before calling start(), eg.:

```
else {
    stopPlayers();
    mp.start();
}

//...

else {
    stopPlayers();
    mp2.start();
}    

//etc
```

Do it for every listener. You might also add checks to see if they are not null.

Comment: How can you do it, if there are N sounds? I mean, this way is hardcoded (5 sounds), can you do it dynamically to N sounds?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you start your media player to play a new sound, stop your media player, then release it and after that instantiate new instance to play the new sound.

for example,

```
if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
     mp.stop();
     mp.release();
}
```

and then you can initalize your media player again as:

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dragunov);
mp.start();
```

Comment: I did as @Gautham said and it worked, but thank you for this it will sure come in handy for shorter codes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can obviously use

```
if(mp.isPlaying()){ 
 mp.stop();
 mp.release();
 }
```

if you don't have to worry about reusing the same activity multiple times.

But if you need to reuse the same MediaPlayer object, try declaring it as a `private static MediaPlayer mp` That should restrict the number of sounds played by `MediaPlayer mp` to just 1.